# Map API response to column colour to indicate which column was changed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api

I have to be able to change the colour of a column in a table depending on a change in the data coming from an api.

I am not able to show my code but can anyone give me an idea of what similar come looks like..I am not the best with API's so any help would be amazing.

The project is using React and TypeScript

Comment: Sounds like you want your columns to track their own seperate state, so they'd have to be components, in order for a single column to change colour.

Answer (score 0):

first of all create a state :

```
const [color,setColor] = useState("")
```

then set color when api is called:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   fetchApi().then((response)=>{
        setColor(response.data.color)
 })
},[])
```

at last step pass the color to the element you want to have dynamic color

```
<table style={{background:color}}></table>
```

this is not the exact code you have to write but i show the steps you have to do to solve it.

Comment: Thanks so much. Each column needs to be a different colour, how would I do that?

Comment: i dont know what is your code logic but you can pass an array or object as state